# Фильтрация многомерного массива по одному значению

Tags: php, json

Не судите строго,я совсем желтоклювый в php. Есть вот такой массив,нужно из него вытащить только те значения(весь массив) в которых 'bti_district_name_list' равен 'Хамовники'. Заранее извиняюсь за то что много воды в массиве.

```
array (size=20)
  0 => 
    array (size=34)
      'outage_id' => string '47327789' (length=8)
      'outage_root_id' => string '47327789' (length=8)
      'address_list' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'улица Сущёвский Вал, дом 60, корпус 1' (length=63)
      'address_list_raw' => 
        array (size=1)
          1784210 => 
            array (size=2)
              'floors' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
              'outage_object_id' => 
                array (size=1)
                  'outage_object' => null
      'outage_kind_name' => string 'Аварийное отключение' (length=39)
      'outage_kind_id' => string '19' (length=2)
      'outage_reason_name' => string 'Неисправность на сетях ХВС' (length=49)
      'outage_type_id' => string '568' (length=3)
      'outage_type_name' => string 'Холодное водоснабжение (ХВС)' (length=52)
      'outage_reason_id' => string '1307' (length=4)
      'outage_reason_root_id' => string '1307' (length=4)
      'plan_date_off' => string '2020-01-09T08:27:12.000Z' (length=24)
      'fact_date_off' => string '2020-01-09T08:27:12.000Z' (length=24)
      'plan_date_on' => string '2020-01-09T10:25:36.000Z' (length=24)
      'fact_date_on' => null
      'note' => string 'Течь сгона на стояке ХВС в квартире ;99' (length=68)
      'initiator_org_name' => null
      'initiator_org_id' => null
      'tp' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'ctp' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'ctp_tp' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'create_date' => string '2020-01-09T08:27:04.421Z' (length=24)
      'create_date_ui' => string '09.01.2020 11:27' (length=16)
      'creator_fio' => null
      'delete_reason' => null
      'is_deleted' => boolean false
      'bti_okrug_name_list' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'ЦАО' (length=6)
      'bti_district_name_list' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Мещанский' (length=18)
      'district' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Мещанский' (length=18)
      'okrug' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'ЦАО' (length=6)
      'bti_okrug_list_id' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1499174' (length=7)
      'bti_district_list_id' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1499253' (length=7)
      'bpm_operation' => null
      'bpm_except' => null
  1 => 
    array (size=34)
      'outage_id' => string '47327571' (length=8)
      'outage_root_id' => string '47327571' (length=8)
      'address_list' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'улица Сущёвский Вал, дом 60, корпус 1' (length=63)
      'address_list_raw' => 
        array (size=1)
          1784210 => 
            array (size=2)
              'floors' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
              'outage_object_id' => 
                array (size=1)
                  'outage_object' => null
      'outage_kind_name' => string 'Аварийное отключение' (length=39)
      'outage_kind_id' => string '19' (length=2)
      'outage_reason_name' => string 'Неисправность на сетях ГВС' (length=49)
      'outage_type_id' => string '569' (length=3)
      'outage_type_name' => string 'Горячее водоснабжение (ГВС)' (length=50)
      'outage_reason_id' => string '1308' (length=4)
      'outage_reason_root_id' => string '1308' (length=4)
      'plan_date_off' => string '2020-01-09T08:25:32.000Z' (length=24)
      'fact_date_off' => string '2020-01-09T08:25:32.000Z' (length=24)
      'plan_date_on' => string '2020-01-09T10:22:40.000Z' (length=24)
      'fact_date_on' => null
      'note' => string 'Течь сгона на стояке ХВС в квартире № 99' (length=71)
      'initiator_org_name' => null
      'initiator_org_id' => null
      'tp' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'ctp' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'ctp_tp' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'create_date' => string '2020-01-09T08:25:24.401Z' (length=24)
      'create_date_ui' => string '09.01.2020 11:25' (length=16)
      'creator_fio' => null
      'delete_reason' => null
      'is_deleted' => boolean false
      'bti_okrug_name_list' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'ЦАО' (length=6)
      'bti_district_name_list' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Мещанский' (length=18)
      'district' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Мещанский' (length=18)
      'okrug' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'ЦАО' (length=6)
      'bti_okrug_list_id' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1499174' (length=7)
      'bti_district_list_id' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1499253' (length=7)
      'bpm_operation' => null
      'bpm_except' => null
  2 => 
    array (size=34)
      'outage_id' => string '47326410' (length=8)
      'outage_root_id' => string '47326410' (length=8)
      'address_list' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Плетешковский переулок, дом 17, строение 1' (length=74)
      'address_list_raw' => 
        array (size=1)
          1550254 => 
            array (size=2)
              'floors' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
              'outage_object_id' => 
                array (size=1)
                  'outage_object' => null
      'outage_kind_name' => string 'Плановое отключение' (length=37)
      'outage_kind_id' => string '20' (length=2)
      'outage_reason_name' => string 'Неисправность на сетях ХВС' (length=49)
      'outage_type_id' => string '568' (length=3)
      'outage_type_name' => string 'Холодное водоснабжение (ХВС)' (length=52)
      'outage_reason_id' => string '1307' (length=4)
      'outage_reason_root_id' => string '1307' (length=4)
      'plan_date_off' => string '2020-01-09T08:11:22.000Z' (length=24)
      'fact_date_off' => string '2020-01-09T08:11:22.000Z' (length=24)
      'plan_date_on' => string '2020-01-09T11:00:22.000Z' (length=24)
      'fact_date_on' => string '2020-01-09T11:00:22.000Z' (length=24)
      'note' => string 'отключение ГВС на дом  и ХВС по стояку кв.97-замена кранов на стояках по заявлению в УК "Экологический фактор"' (length=196)
      'initiator_org_name' => null
      'initiator_org_id' => null
      'tp' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'ctp' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'ctp_tp' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'create_date' => string '2020-01-09T08:15:44.354Z' (length=24)
      'create_date_ui' => string '09.01.2020 11:15' (length=16)
      'creator_fio' => null
      'delete_reason' => null
      'is_deleted' => boolean false
      'bti_okrug_name_list' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'ЦАО' (length=6)
      'bti_district_name_list' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Басманный' (length=18)
      'district' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Басманный' (length=18)
      'okrug' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'ЦАО' (length=6)
      'bti_okrug_list_id' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1499174' (length=7)
      'bti_district_list_id' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1499203' (length=7)
      'bpm_operation' => null
      'bpm_except' => null
  3 => 
    array (size=34)
      'outage_id' => string '47326379' (length=8)
      'outage_root_id' => string '47326379' (length=8)
      'address_list' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Плетешковский переулок, дом 17, строение 1' (length=74)
      'address_list_raw' => 
        array (size=1)
          1550254 => 
            array (size=2)
              'floors' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
              'outage_object_id' => 
                array (size=1)
                  'outage_object' => null
      'outage_kind_name' => string 'Плановое отключение' (length=37)
      'outage_kind_id' => string '20' (length=2)
      'outage_reason_name' => string 'Неисправность на сетях ГВС' (length=49)
      'outage_type_id' => string '569' (length=3)
      'outage_type_name' => string 'Горячее водоснабжение (ГВС)' (length=50)
      'outage_reason_id' => string '1308' (length=4)
      'outage_reason_root_id' => string '1308' (length=4)
      'plan_date_off' => string '2020-01-09T08:11:22.000Z' (length=24)
      'fact_date_off' => string '2020-01-09T08:11:22.000Z' (length=24)
      'plan_date_on' => string '2020-01-09T11:00:22.000Z' (length=24)
      'fact_date_on' => string '2020-01-09T11:00:22.000Z' (length=24)
      'note' => string 'отключение ГВС на дом  и ХВС по стояку кв.97-замена кранов на стояках по заявлению в УК "Экологический фактор"' (length=196)
      'initiator_org_name' => null
      'initiator_org_id' => null
      'tp' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'ctp' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'ctp_tp' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'create_date' => string '2020-01-09T08:15:28.763Z' (length=24)
      'create_date_ui' => string '09.01.2020 11:15' (length=16)
      'creator_fio' => null
      'delete_reason' => null
      'is_deleted' => boolean false
      'bti_okrug_name_list' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'ЦАО' (length=6)
      'bti_district_name_list' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Басманный' (length=18)
      'district' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Басманный' (length=18)
      'okrug' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'ЦАО' (length=6)
      'bti_okrug_list_id' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1499174' (length=7)
      'bti_district_list_id' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1499203' (length=7)
      'bpm_operation' => null
      'bpm_except' => null
  4 => 
    array (size=34)
      'outage_id' => string '47326281' (length=8)
      'outage_root_id' => string '47326281' (length=8)
      'address_list' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Чесменская улица, дом 7, п. "2", "3", "1"' (length=60)
      'address_list_raw' => 
        array (size=1)
          1528986 => 
            array (size=4)
              'flats' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
              'floors' => 
                array (size=0)
                  empty
              'entrances' => 
                array (size=3)
                  0 => string '2' (length=1)
                  1 => string '3' (length=1)
                  2 => string '1' (length=1)
              'outage_object_id' => 
                array (size=1)
                  'outage_object' => null
      'outage_kind_name' => string 'Аварийное отключение' (length=39)
      'outage_kind_id' => string '19' (length=2)
      'outage_reason_name' => string 'Ремонтные работы на сетях ГВС' (length=54)
      'outage_type_id' => string '569' (length=3)
      'outage_type_name' => string 'Горячее водоснабжение (ГВС)' (length=50)
      'outage_reason_id' => string '1297' (length=4)
      'outage_reason_root_id' => string '1297' (length=4)
      'plan_date_off' => string '2020-01-09T08:14:19.000Z' (length=24)
      'fact_date_off' => string '2020-01-09T08:14:19.000Z' (length=24)
      'plan_date_on' => string '2020-01-09T09:00:02.000Z' (length=24)
      'fact_date_on' => null
      'note' => string 'Ремонтные работы на сетях ГВС' (length=54)
      'initiator_org_name' => string 'ГБУ «ЖИЛИЩНИК ТАГАНСКОГО РАЙОНА»' (length=61)
      'initiator_org_id' => string '62749' (length=5)
      'tp' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'ctp' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'ctp_tp' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'create_date' => string '2020-01-09T08:14:18.459Z' (length=24)
      'create_date_ui' => string '09.01.2020 11:14' (length=16)
      'creator_fio' => null
      'delete_reason' => null
      'is_deleted' => boolean false
      'bti_okrug_name_list' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'ЦАО' (length=6)
      'bti_district_name_list' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Таганский' (length=18)
      'district' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Таганский' (length=18)
      'okrug' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'ЦАО' (length=6)
      'bti_okrug_list_id' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1499174' (length=7)
      'bti_district_list_id' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1499229' (length=7)
      'bpm_operation' => null
      'bpm_except' => null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array_filter($array, function($v) { 
    return isset($v['bti_district_name_list']) 
    && $v['bti_district_name_list'] == 'Хамовники'; 
});
var_dump($result)
```

Comment: извините, а в таком случае как вывести результат через var_dump?

Comment: array_filter - возвращает отфильрованный массив.

Comment: выводит пустой массив. может быть по тому что 'bti_district_name_list' является именем массива а не ключа?